# Getting "GRUB loading ... no such partition"?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, error-logging

I am having a dual os, windows 7 and linux,

the c drive have 20 GB, in which 5 GB is allocated for windows 7 (original) and 15 gb for linux

since the spacing for windows is very low i used EaseUS partition manager and deleted my linux OS, and merged the unused space into my C drive, now it becomes 20GB, the things, after the reboot,

I am getting

> GRUB loading.
>
> > Welcome to GRUB!
> >
> > > error: no such partition.
> > >
> > > > entering rescue mode. . .

Kindly help me guys

the problem i am facing is i dont have a DVD drive to resolve it, using recovery mode.

Waiting for your reply guys.

in ls command

i have

(hd0) (hd0,msdos8) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

Comment: Sounds like you deleted the wrong partition :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your MBR (master boot record) to point to the windows 7 install. Installing Linux replaces your windows MBR with GRUB and simply deleting the linux partition does not remove GRUB.

The easiest way to fix your MBR is to have a recovery disc but you don't seem to have one so you'll have to google how to do it with

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This site is made for professionals, and as such, we expect professional answers. Instead of telling a user to Google it, you need to provide an answer in order for the site to help grow. If you find the answer, post the instructions (use [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/472355/edit)) here and reference the site you found it from